# Complex structured JSON Iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I m trying to iterate over the below JSON Object using this code :

```
$.each(response.payload.entries, function (i, data) {

            var title = data.uid;
            var dis = data.text;
            var url = data.http;
});
```

And this is the JSON Object I m trying to iterate over.

```
for (;;);
{
   "__ar":1,
   "payload":{
      "entries":[
         {
            "uid":617823537,
            "photo":"http:\/\/profile.ak.fbcdn.net\/hprofile-ak-snc4\/371505_617823537_1432230628_q.jpg",
            "type":"user",
            "text":"Nikh Il",
            "path":"\/nikh.il.351",
            "category":"Pune, Maharashtra",
            "names":[
               "Nikh Il"
            ],
            "subtext":""
         },
         {
            "uid":100001702504174,
            "photo":"http:\/\/profile.ak.fbcdn.net\/hprofile-ak-ash2\/157844_100001702504174_408730515_q.jpg",
            "type":"user",
            "text":"Nilam Patil",
            "path":"\/profile.php?id=100001702504174",
            "category":"Pune, Maharashtra",
            "names":[
               "Nilam Patil"
            ],
            "subtext":""
         },
         {
            "uid":100001485070815,
            "photo":"http:\/\/profile.ak.fbcdn.net\/hprofile-ak-snc4\/48955_100001485070815_1517928098_q.jpg",
            "type":"user",
            "text":"Nisha Lemos",
            "path":"\/profile.php?id=100001485070815",
            "category":"Pune, Maharashtra",
            "names":[
               "Nisha Lemos"
            ],
            "subtext":""
         },
         {
            "uid":100002112294701,
            "photo":"http:\/\/profile.ak.fbcdn.net\/hprofile-ak-snc4\/48784_100002112294701_37411980_q.jpg",
            "type":"user",
            "text":"Nilesh Pathare",
            "path":"\/profile.php?id=100002112294701",
            "category":"Pune, Maharashtra",
            "names":[
               "Nilesh Pathare"
            ],
            "subtext":""
         },
         {
            "uid":100003485631681,
            "photo":"http:\/\/profile.ak.fbcdn.net\/hprofile-ak-snc4\/173739_100003485631681_1898829160_q.jpg",
            "type":"user",
            "text":"Nilesh Pathare",
            "path":"\/profile.php?id=100003485631681",
            "category":"Pune, Maharashtra",
            "names":[
               "Nilesh Pathare"
            ],
            "subtext":""
         },
         {
            "uid":100002020083795,
            "photo":"http:\/\/profile.ak.fbcdn.net\/hprofile-ak-ash2\/276120_100002020083795_155025323_q.jpg",
            "type":"user",
            "text":"Nikhil Pataskar",
            "path":"\/nikpataskar",
            "category":"Pune, Maharashtra",
            "names":[
               "Nikhil Pataskar"
            ],
            "subtext":""
         },
         {
            "uid":100000619107842,
            "photo":"http:\/\/profile.ak.fbcdn.net\/hprofile-ak-snc4\/260864_100000619107842_139211244_q.jpg",
            "type":"user",
            "text":"Nikhil Agarwal",
            "path":"\/profile.php?id=100000619107842",
            "category":"Pune, Maharashtra",
            "names":[
               "Nikhil Agarwal"
            ],
            "subtext":""
         },
         {
            "uid":137827210650,
            "type":"app",
            "path":"http:\/\/apps.facebook.com\/ninjasaga\/",
            "text":"Ninja Saga",
            "dataGT":"{\"ref\":\"search_typeahead\",\"type\":\"click2canvas\"}",
            "subtext":"4,100,000 monthly users",
            "category":"Game",
            "photo":"http:\/\/photos-f.ak.fbcdn.net\/photos-ak-snc7\/v43\/150\/137827210650\/app_1_137827210650_3577.gif"
         },
         {
            "uid":102796083108857,
            "type":"app",
            "path":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/apps\/application.php?id=102796083108857",
            "text":"Nimbuzz Mobile",
            "subtext":"5,600,000 monthly users",
            "category":"App",
            "photo":"http:\/\/photos-g.ak.fbcdn.net\/photos-ak-snc7\/v27562\/173\/102796083108857\/app_1_102796083108857_3242.gif"
         },
         {
            "uid":84697719333,
            "type":"app",
            "path":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/apps\/application.php?id=84697719333",
            "text":"Nike",
            "subtext":"470,000 monthly users",
            "category":"App",
            "photo":"http:\/\/photos-a.ak.fbcdn.net\/photos-ak-snc7\/v85006\/213\/84697719333\/app_1_84697719333_5631.gif"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I get this error in the JS Console

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

I get the error now !! Its the for (;;);

How do I replace that with some whitespace so that it remains a valid JSON Object ?

Comment: This is not a JSON object. It's text which is evaluated as JavaScript, which is not valid. The error comes from parsing `{ "__ar":1,`, where `{` is interpreted as the start of a block. The colon is syntactically wrong in this context.

Comment: But I checked it on http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: And it says that its a Valid JSON Object !!

Comment: If I copy and past what you posted, I get the error *"The JSON Data field does not contain JSON data."*. The `for (;;);` makes the text not being JSON. If you remove it, you'd have valid JSON.

Comment: Ok ! I can remove that! But how about iterating over it

Comment: What you have should work, if `response` is parsed correctly into a JavaScript object.

Comment: I need to iterate over entry individually to collect UID's, etc

Comment: So? `$.each(response.payload.entries, function (i, data) {` seems to be doing that. If you don't know how `$.each` works, have a look the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/). If you don't know how to access object properties, have a look at [Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects). Then try to access each level of the object step by step. Set breakpoints, inspect variables.

Comment: I need to remove those for (;;); from the first line of the page !

Comment: @Felix Kling Is there a way I can replace the for(;;); !! And the Object still remains the same

Comment: Where does this not-quite JSON come from? If you control the source you should remove the `for(;;);` yourself on the web server side, not in JS in the browser. If it is a normal Ajax request to your own webserver and for some reason you can't change the response then change your jQuery Ajax call to use `dataType:"text"` so that your `response` variable is a string instead of an (automatically parsed) object, and then use the String `.replace()` or `.substr()` methods to remove the `for(;;);` before parsing the resulting JSON yourself with `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: P.S. If you are doing a JSONP request to another domain then (to the best of my knowledge) you will not be able to process that response using JavaScript/jQuery - it is simply not a valid JSONP response.

Answer (score 0):

For this task, you can use DefiantJS (http://defiantjs.com). This lib extends the global object JSON with the method "search" with XPath queries. It returns matches in an array (empty array if no matches were found).

Here is a working fiddle of the code below;
http://jsfiddle.net/hbi99/KZ68m/

```
var data = {
       "__ar": 1,
       "payload": {
          "entries": [
            ...
          ]
       }
    },
    res = JSON.search( data, '//payload/entries' );

for (var i=0; i<res.length; i++) {
    console.log( res[i] );
}
```

If you aren't familiar with XPath (which is standardised query language), you can try out this XPath evaluator to give you an idea of how easy it is.
http://defiantjs.com/#xpath_evaluator